# CComboBox automatically selects text after call to MoveWindow

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, ccombobox

I'm currently experiencing a very strange problem with a `CComboBox` used within a `CFormView`.

After adding strings to the combobox (created with `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_VSCROLL | CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_SORT | CBS_AUTOHSCROLL`), I'm selecting an entry via `CComboBox::SetCurSel` and resize the combobox via `MoveWindow` in the `OnSize()` handler of the `CFormView` derived class.

As soon as I include the call to `MoveWindow`, the whole text in the edit part of the combobox gets selected. If I remove the call to `MoveWindow`, the text doesn't get selected. This happens not only for one, but for all comboboxes used.

I'm somehow lost at this point. Any hint is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting all the text is standard Windows behavior when a combo box gets focus.  I guess the MoveWindow is resetting the focus on the control.

Try using CComboBox::SetEditSel to remove the selection after MoveWindow.

Comment: OK, thanks. I thought I'm doing something wrong and missed an option to prevent the text from being selected.